# Sci-fi short story about a woman who finds out she'll probably die if she gives birth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I can't remember a lot of details, but the basic plot, I *think*, is that doctors can now kind of tell if a pregnant person will die while having a child, so the pregnant person can choose whether or not to deliver.

I think the story is about a woman who finds out that she’ll probably die, but she and her husband are trying to figure it out. I think the husband pushes her in some way (to do it or not), and the government pulls up and are like: *"This was all a plan; we heard everything and you’re going to jail, buddy,"* and the husband goes to jail.

That is literally all I can remember, and I don't know if I'm misremembering anything. I read this story in my 12th grade sci-fi class.

Comment: When were you in 12th grade?

Comment: Is this science fictional?

Comment: @DavidW - From the description, it sounds like some *Minority Report* situation, not medical risk prediction.

Comment: I wish I'd had a 12th grade sci-fi reading class, instead of having to do Shakespeare